# Convert List<IDictionary<string, string>> to strongly typed list in C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Using C#, I have the following list using IDictionary:

```
List<IDictionary<string, string>> lstDictionary;
```

After I populate the list above, I need to convert it to a strongly typed list based on a class:

```
public class customer
    {
        public string FirstName{ get; set; }
        public string LastName{ get; set; }
        public string Status{ get; set; }
    }
List<customer> lstCustomers;
```

So now, I am trying to convert using LAMBDA/LINQ but not working (Shows error message on p.FirstName):

```
lstCustomers = lstDictionary.Select(p => new customer
            {
                FirstName = p.FirstName,
                LastName = p.LastName,
                Status = p.Status
            }).ToList();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is your `class customer` mutable? (and why isn't it `PascalCased`?)

Comment: Hint: what is the **type** of `p`?

Comment: `Shows error message on p.FirstName` what error is that, it's not in your post. Also how are you populating `lstDictionary`? Finally, why populate that and then you want to convert all records to a new type `List<customer>`? Why not just create a `List<customer>` in the first place?

Comment: @RobertSmith: You have an answer below (and you've accepted it). Unlike other sites, we don't update the question to include the answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember, each `p` in the call to `Select` is an `IDictionary<string, string>`. In .Net you use an indexer to access elements in a Dictionary; there is no `p.FirstName`, but there might be a `p["FirstName"]`.

So *assuming the keys are always setup correctly* it will look like this:

```
lstCustomers = lstDictionary.Select(p => new customer
        {
            FirstName = p["FirstName"],
            LastName = p["LastName"],
            Status = p["Status"]
        }).ToList();
```

Finally, I need to point out the "might" in my first paragraph. This has the potential to blow up at runtime if the Dictionary ends up with unexpected data. In the .Net world this is considered poor design and is usually the result of mistake made earlier. Sometimes you're far enough down the line you push on anyway, but the mistake is still there.

Comment: Someone can't decide if they like this or not :D

Comment: Joel, thank you very much!!  I just tested it and it works perfect.  Thank  you again.  Yes, the data is coming from another system and that is the format but yes I agree its not the best design.  But your solution works perfect.